# Understanding user_password and user_birthday of phpbb2

Tags: phpbb

I am working to transfer a phpbb2 forum to bbpress. One of the things that I need to know is to understand these two formats so that I can properly transfer them to bbpress.

Can anyone tell how phpbb2 encrypts these two information ?

user_password (varchar (32))
user_birthday (int)

Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user_password is an MD5 hash.

user_birthday doesn't exist in a standard phpbb2 database so probably added by a modification, this would most likely be a unix timestamp.

Comment: Thanks Eiji. Any idea how can get the real value, or transform that to bbpress compatible format ?
For user_birthday, it has small numeric values, like 30 Nov 1978 is written as 3255.

Comment: ah, not unix timestamp then, as 3255 translates to Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:54:15 GMT. I'm unsure of the password hash bbpress uses so if it is something different to MD5 I'm out of ideas as they aren't able to be decoded.

Comment: If it's Terrafrost's birthday hack, I think that birthdays are stored as month, day, year and then split up later for display. So 3255 would really be 3/2/55 - March 2nd 1955. Hopefully that helps